# Excel Macro in VBA - How to apply a loop to move down columns

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a sub Macro that basically works as a currency converter that allows the user to define their own exchange rate values. I have tested it on one cell and works fine but I need it to loop and move down a row for a define range. (Currently the cells defined are L2, K2 and G", need to to repeat on L3, K3 and G3 until Ln, Kn and Gn etc.)

Code is as follows:

```
Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'

Dim score As String, result As String
score = Sheets("Paste Orders Here").Range("K2").Value

If score = "USD" Then
    result = Sheets("Paste Orders Here").Range("L2") * Sheets("Configuration").Range("C5")
ElseIf score = "EUR" Then
    result = Sheets("Paste Orders Here").Range("L2") * Sheets("Configuration").Range("B5")
ElseIf score = "GBP" Then
    result = Sheets("Paste Orders Here").Range("L2")
ElseIf score = "" Then
    result = Sheets("Paste Orders Here").Range("K2")
End If

Sheets("Brightpearl").Range("G2").Value = result
'
End Sub
```

Thanks, I understand this could be completely incorrect for wanting to apply this to multiple rows but I could really use some help!

Comment: Use a `For` Loop? I can give you the answer but I want you to try it first?

Comment: Why VBA at all? Why not just do this with a formula in the `Brightpear1` sheet that you can drag through all the rows you need - Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, it's part of a larger macro where order details are pasted into one sheet, and the macro manipulates it into another.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, when I apply a `For` loop I get errors regarding the identifiers when I change K2 to Ki for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my interpretation. I wasn't quite sure how far to fill the formulas down as you only referred to this as *n* so I used the bottom of *Paste Orders Here*'s column L.

```
Sub Macro9()
    Dim r As Long, lr As Long
    With Sheets("Paste Orders Here")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lr
            Select Case UCase(.Cells(r, "K").Value)
                Case "USD"
                    Sheets("Brightpearl").Cells(r, "G") = _
                      CCur(.Cells(r, "L").Value * Sheets("Configuration").Range("C5").Value)
                Case "EUR"
                    Sheets("Brightpearl").Cells(r, "G") = _
                      CCur(.Cells(r, "L").Value * Sheets("Configuration").Range("B5").Value)
                Case "GBP"
                    Sheets("Brightpearl").Cells(r, "G") = CCur(.Cells(r, "L").Value)
                Case Else
                    Sheets("Brightpearl").Cells(r, "G") = .Cells(r, "K").Value
            End Select
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

I find a *Select Case* method works well in these cases and provides ease of future expandability.

Comment: Nice one cheers, didn't even think of using a Select Case! Like I said I wrote it for one set of cells so assumed I wasn't writing it correctly for a range. Thanks for your help

Comment: @A Anderson - Thanks! I made three minor edits. CCur in place of CDbl, there was one missing one prefix period (.), and lr should have been based on K, not L as the Select Case was based on K.